# doAnswer() in PowerMockito not working

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

Here I am trying to return null while invoking `create()` method which is inside `createContact()` method and mocking `create()` method with `anySting()` parameters. But whenever I am invoking this method it is returning `InvalidDataException` eventhough I mocked with `anyString()`

Here is my `@Test` method to test `createContact` method

```
@Test
   public void testCreateContact() throws Exception{
       Contact contact = new Contact();    
       ContactHelper mockObj = PowerMockito.mock(Helper.class);
       PowerMockito.whenNew(Helper.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockObj);
       doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                return null;
            }
            }).when(spy).createContact(anyString(),(Contact)anyObject(),anyString());
       doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                return null;
            }
            }).when(mockObj).create(anyString(),anyString(),(Contact)anyObject());

       obj.createContact("realmId", contact, appId);
   }
```

Below is my `createContact` method,

```
public void createContact(String id, Contact contact, String uid) throws CareException{
        Helper helper = new Helper();
        try {
            helper.create(id, uid, contact);
        } catch (CareException ex) {
            if(!contact.isDeleted() && contact.isAccountCreateOnFailureEnabled() && ex.getMessage().matches("Code=Account")){
                handlemethod(id, contact, uid);
                return;
            }
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Somecases I am throwing `careException` manually, even in that Im getting same `invalidDataException`

Comment: try to add the stacktrace